# why browser shows \u0627\u062c\u062a\u0645\u0627\u0639\u06cc and etc instead of real utf8 characters?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, unicode, utf-8

I set utf8 for my PHP code:

```
<html>
<head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<?php 
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
if (isset($_REQUEST['op'])){
    $op = $_REQUEST['op'];
} else {
    echo "Invalid op";
exit;
}
```

and also for database connection:

```
function db_connect(){
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ex");
    mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    return $con;
}
```

and I saved my records as `utf8` characters in my database and set collation as `utf8_general` and use `SET NAMES utf8;` in SQL.
but I see this unicode in the browser instead of my real records in db!
what can I do to see my real records as persian letters on the browser?
THANK YOU FOR ANSWERING SOON

Comment: Browsers show what they get. What does the HTML they get look like?

Comment: ensure that you dont have other charset header, and all your files are saved in utf8 encoding

Comment: I dont have any special HTML code dear. my project is just server side but when I want to test my functions to get persian letters data from database I see this unicode! @JukkaK.Korpela

Comment: I have just one PHP file contain my web services functions and I'm sure as I said every thing is saved in utf8! @Serg

Comment: What you see in a browser still depends on the HTML it gets. You need to find out what it is and then analyze why your PHP code generates that.

Comment: well if you are sure then everything is fine. Browser doesnt understand your output - go find a reason: header, html charset, output charset of content. There shoudnt be other reasons